# mysql "Lock wait timeout exceeded" two transaction with different keys indexed

Tags: mysql, locking, timeout, wait

I have set of tables that I need to delete their records with a specific key and insert new records. Different transactions are used one for each key:

Transaction 1:

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id=1; -- many records
DELETE FROM table2 WHERE id=1; -- many records
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1,...),...; -- many records
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (1,...),...; -- many records
```

Transaction 2:

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id=2; -- many records
DELETE FROM table2 WHERE id=2; -- many records
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (2,...),...; -- many records
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (2,...),...; -- many records
```

When the two transactions are running at the same time, I get the lock wait timeout exceeded error for one of them. The id for both table is indexed, so it should be row based locking, why do I still get this error?

Comment: Are the tables MyISAM or InnoDB?

Comment: You might do better asking this on [dba.se]

Comment: Tables are InnoDB @BillKarwin

Comment: I will post it on DB Admin too, thanks

Comment: Yeah, now that I look it up, that error message is specific to InnoDB. It seems MyISAM does not time out, it'll hang forever.

Comment: I could increase the timeout duration but, since I have the key indexed, it shouldn't lock the whole table, just the rows with the given key should be locked

Comment: `DELETE` statements generally set record locks on every index record that is scanned in the processing of the SQL statement.  See [Locks Set by Different SQL Statements in `InnoDB`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/innodb-locks-set.html).

Comment: @eggyal you are right, when using index, it should directly go to the records with given id, so it shouldn't scan other records with different id, and therefore shouldn't lock other records

Comment: @Navid, it's true only for unique indexes, but for not unique indexes MySlq perform gap lock and next-key locks to prevent phantom reads, see this link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-record-level-locks.html